Worshipping the Worldly Bread of Jesus? - John 6
Context & Question. In John 6, one detail which is very heavily emphasized is about how the crowd of "disciples" are following Jesus not for the purpose of receiving spiritual bread, but rather for worldly bread (or -- more generally -- worldly goods). Upon having applied this teaching to my way of life, I have found myself a little confused: What exactly constitutes as the analogue of "worldly bread"? (More specifically, so as to fit within the guidelines of appropriate questions for this site, what does scripture indicate as being such?)
Obvious Examples. (i) Politicians using the name of God to further their political agendas. (ii) People expressing their love for Jesus with the intent of adopting a "holier than thou" mentality.
Confusing Examples. (i) Giving thanks to God for all the joy He had put into my life. (ii) Giving thanks to God for the "roof over my head", for access to clean drinking water, for loving environment of people He has gifted me with, etc.
In the latter examples, would I not simply be giving praise to Jesus for the sole intent of all the worldly luxuries I have received in His holy name? And therefore, how am I any different from those who were amongst the crowd of people following Jesus? I appreciate any responses I can get. May the Holy Spirit guide you in your responses. Thank you!

I made your post a wiki post as that seemed better than requesting people not vote on it.

@curiousdannii Thank you for making this edit. Is it possible for me to automatically enable this feature on all my posts? Or is it something only moderators and such can do?

I think you can do it, unless you need more reputation points? I don't remember exactly.

We may find an answer from Jesus in Matthew 6:31-33;

31 So do not worry, saying, ‘What shall we eat?’ or ‘What shall we drink?’ or ‘What shall we wear?’ 32 For the pagans run after all these things, and your heavenly Father knows that you need them. 33 But seek first his kingdom and his righteousness, and all these things will be given to you as well.

The concept of "worldly bread" serves as a metaphor for those who prioritize their earthly desires. These desires, named by OP as "Obvious Examples", whether for material possessions or fame, ofter lead people astray from God. Conversely, those who nourish themselves with "spiritual bread" prioritize seeking the Lord's kingdom and righteousness over personal gain. They willingly forsake worldly treasure in exchange for the promise of eternal life.
Gratitude is paramount in acknowledging the blessings bestowed upon us by God, However, it's natural to wonder why seemingly underserving individuals prosper while others struggle. Does the prosperity of some imply greater worthiness than those who possess little yet remain steadfast in their gratitude to God?
In Luke 21:1-4, a poor widow offers only two coins to the temple treasury, significantly less than others. Yet, Jesus praises her, telling His disciples;

3 “Truly I tell you,” he said, “this poor widow has put in more than all the others. 4 All these people gave their gifts out of their wealth; but she out of her poverty put in all she had to live on.”

Therefore, when we focus on seeking the Lord's kingdom and righteousness, these "Confusing Examples" cited in the question may diminish.

If in Hitler’s Germany you risk your life hiding your Jewish neighbor, say, Stella, for you consider this to be your Christian duty to do so; and this Stella Grinberg, your neighbor, happens to be a hell of a pretty lass and moreover falls in love, first, with your moral uprightness and then also with you personally; and, moreover, you also fall in love with her, and so, this rare thing, happiness of reciprocated love downed in your life as a pleasant gift of providence; and moreover, as an icing on the cake of your life, her uncle Aaron Grinberg who died in the US, happened to have bestowed on Stella, his only niece, several millions of US $s, so that your future comfortable conjugal life and your children’s high quality education us fully guaranteed! - you can and even should - for it will be utterly ungrateful for you not to - thank Christ for all these, but first of all you must thank Him for emboldening you with His salvific grace to such an extent that you were able to risk your life for a Jewish neighbor, no matter was she pretty as Hellen of Troy or ugly as a witch from Walt Disney’s “Cinderella”.
P.S. Unfortunately, Stella Grinberg’s cooking abilities were lower than mediocre, but one cannot get full paradise on earth and some things should be suffered here as malum necessarium.

(i) I'm not asking whether it is okay to give thanks to God for all these things -- I'd imagine it's possibly better for a politician to give thanks to God if He in fact did give that person power, rather than not give thanks for it -- but whether this is all which you are to give thanks for? (ii) As much as I love the narration you have provided, I would appreciate scripturally-motivated over narratively-constructed responses. :) Thank you for the insight though!! I do appreciate it.

@JAG131 Sorry but if we want Christ only for benefits of this life, moreover, if we do not lose our very lives for Him and for His gospel, then even if we thank Him quintillion times a day for earthly gifts - power, money, health, romantic love, piña colladas on Hawaii beaches etc. we will pleasantly and thankfully go to hell, 100%.

Right, so how are we supposed to give worship if not for the ways which He has made our lives so much better?

@JAG131 Your life can be made better even without Christ: just work hard, gain more money, go to Hawaii and drink your piña coladas and have infatuating romantic nights with best girls, - what can be better! But what has Christ to do with all that, do not also atheists and agnostics do the same? and in the afterlife also Muslims do the same with their daily 70 virgins, although without piña coladas, for in Islamic paradise there is a shortage of those? Nobody is worthy of Christ who is not losing his life for Him, it is He who said this, not me (cf. Matthew  10:39).

“Your life can be made better even without Christ” but it is only from him in which true peace is attained (as explained throughout Philippians, Corinthians, etc. Philippians 4:6-7 is an example of you want exact verse citations). You can work hard and do all the things you say, but ultimately without Jesus, you won’t truly ever be satisfied. And what do you mean by “losing [your] life for him”? Are you asserting that one is a true follower if and only if they’d be willing to would die a physical death in defense of Jesus? Or those who are willing to make personal sacrifices in his name?

But this still doesn’t answer my question as to why we worship Jesus if not for the peace he gives? I’m trying to understand, but it doesn’t appear as though the Holy Spirit is speaking through you when you dodge this question. (Also, we don’t worship out of fear of Hell. Otherwise, we end up worshipping in legalistic manner, which contradict a core tenant of scripture which states that we are to worship with our hearts.

@JAG131 What peace does He give? What you mean in "peace" in the first place? If earthly comforts and good salary with strong health, then it is not the Christly peace, but if you mean crucifying your sinful inclinations, crucifying the entire world for you and of yourself to the world so that Christ may start live in you and you say with Paul, "not I am alive any more, but lives in me Christ", if that peace you mean, then yes, you should incessantly thank Christ for this, and for anything else, even a good job, health, salary and a pretty wife, but without first the latter will not save you.

I tend to define “true peace” as “peace of mind”, or rather the Fruits of the Holy Spirit. (So joy, love, patience, etc etc.) Though this definition hasn’t been pondered on enough for me to claim it as correct. You still have yet to answer my question…it would be helpful to hear an answer.

@JAG131 Haven't I? Then can you reformulate your question as clearly as possible? "Peace of mind" is so ambiguous a term! Seems like some oriental guru-inspired, Buddhist or Zen or whatsoever. Christian Peace is that which world cannot give (John 14:27), but only Christ can give, and this "give" means that He Himself lives in you through you vanquishing sinful drives in yourself through prayers and fasting and fulfilling the divine commandments.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
